# No route error for nested resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi this is my first time using nested resources. I did `rake routes` and found a path to new_user_album_path, but it doesn't seem to work. Could the problem be because I did a double nest?

The problem is specifically when I click a link in my Users views file named show.html.erb . Trying to link to a "create an album" page but that's when it shows me an error:

`No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"albums"}`

Here are my files:

show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Welcome, #{@user.name}!") %>


<div>
    You currently have <%= pluralize(@user.albums.count, "album") %>
</div>

<div>
    <%= link_to "Create a new album!", new_user_album_path %>
</div>

<div>
<% if @user.albums.any? %>
hey
<% else %>
boo
<% end %>

</div>

<%= link_to "Back", users_path %>
```

Config/routes

```
Pholder::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users do
  resources :albums do
    resources :pictures
  end
end
```

Controller

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @albums = Albums.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @albums }
    end
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the user to the route method, like:

```
new_user_album_path(@user)
```

Comment: Common mistake.  Routing errors are one of the things you have to learn to decipher because of their polymorphic nature.  In this case passing an undefined variable causes the lookup of a different, non-existent route.